# What are the advantages of strict consistency over sequential consistency in the field of cache consistency？

Tags: caching, cpu, cpu-cache, consistency

When the lock is implemented, both `strict consistency` and `sequential consistency` only need `cas` (`tas`) instructions, and neither need `barriers`. Since there is no observer of the physical world on the cpu, the consistency of the observer's perspective has no practical meaning.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not really familiar with the definition of strict consistency.

Below is a long story with a high risk of information overload, but I hope it will show how coherence fits in memory consistency models or at least give you enough structure to look for additional information.

Cache coherence is normally defined in terms of sequential consistency (SC) per location. SC doesn't need to respect the real time order of requests; so reads and writes can be skewed as long as the program order (PO) is preserved. This prevents SC from being composable, so if you would have a cache of coherent locations (so SC per location), then the cache as a whole doesn't need to be SC (with PO per location). The consequence is that there is no guarantee a total order over the memory order exist that can explain the execution. So in simple terms, you can't build a SC cache if the cache is only SC per location.

If coherence would be implemented using linearizability per location instead of SC per location, then a linearizable cache can be made (with PO per location). This is also called 'atomic memory'.

With linearizability the real time order of a request is respected. The advantage of linearizability is that it is composable. So if you would have a system of linearizable locations, then the cache as as a whole will be linearizable. As a consequence there always exist at least 1 total order over the memory order that explains the execution. So if the CPU would prevent any reordering of loads/stores before they hit the cache, in combination with a linearizable cache, you can create an SC CPU.

A typical protocol for cache coherence is MESI: write needs to wait till the cache line has been invalidated on all CPU's before it can write the change to the cache line. The consequence of this approach is that MESI based caches are linearizable.

Most CPU's have store buffers, so an older store can be reordered with a newer load to a different address and as a consequence the memory order doesn't order older stores with newer loads to a different address. So the [StoreLoad] is dropped as requirement for the memory order. Dropping the [StoreLoad] doesn't prevent you from having a total order over all memory accesses it just means that the memory model doesn't care in which order they can be found in the total order over the memory order.

The key problem here is when a store is followed by a load to the same address. There are 2 solutions possible:

1 (A strict solution): The loads needs to wait for the store to be committed to the cache before the load can be executed. The advantage of this approach is that the load and stores are properly ordered in the memory order and a total order over the memory order exists. This is the memory model of the IBM-370. So IBM-370 is SC + dropping [StoreLoad].

2 (a relaxed solution) The load looks inside the store buffer. If there is a match, it will return the stored value. This is called store to load forwarding (STLF).  The problem here is that it isn't possible to create a total order over the memory order because the store isn't atomic; a load is by definition globally ordered after the store it reads from, but because the load is performed (load from the store buffer) before the store is globally performed (committed to the cache), the store and load to the same address are not properly ordered in the memory order. This is demonstrated with the following test:

```
A=B=0

CPU1:
   A=1
   r1=A
   r2=B

CPU2:
   B=1
   r3=B
   r4=A
```

With STLF it can be that r1=1, r2=0, r3=1, r4=0, but with IBM-370/SC/Linearizability it would not be possible. In the above example the load of r1=A is ordered both after A=1 and before A=1 (due to STLF). So a total order over all memory actions doesn't exist because the load would be ordered both before and after the store. Instead the requirements of the memory model are relaxed to a total order over all stores need to exist. And this is how we get the Total Store Order, the memory model of the X86. So TSO is a relaxation of SC whereby the [StoreLoad] is dropped + STLF.

We can relax the memory order further. So with TSO we have the guarantee that at least 1 total order over all the stores exist, but this is because the cache is linearizable. If we would relax this requirement, we get processor consistency (PC). So PC allows for an older store to be reordered with a newer load, and requires a coherent cache, but writes to different addresses made by different CPUs can be seen out of order (so no total order over the stores).

This is demonstrated using the Independent Reads of Independent writes (IRIW) litmus test

```
A=B=0

CPU1
   A=1
CPU2
   B=1
CPU3:
   r1=A
   r2=B
CPU4:
   r3=B
   r4=A
```

Can it be that we see r=1,r2=0,r3=1,r4=0. So can it be that CPU3 and CPU4 see the writes to A,B in different orders? If a total order over the stores exist (e.g. TSO/IBM-370/SC/Linearizability), then this isn't possible. But on PC, this is allowed.

I hope this example makes it clear that 'just' a coherent cache is still a pretty weak property.

Linearizability, SC and IBM-370 are also called atomic/store-atomic/single-copy store atomic because there is only a single copy of the data. There is a logical point where the store becomes visible to all CPUs.
TSO is called multi copy store atomic because a store can become visible to the issuing CPU early (STLF).
A memory model like PC is called non atomic (or non store atomic) because there is no logical moment where a store becomes visible to other CPUs.

A CAS instruction is not just sequential consistent; it is linearizable. And depending on the architecture, a CAS involves fences. E.g. an atomic instruction like a CMPXCHG on the X86 has an implicit lock which will act like a full barrier. So it is guarantees to preserve all 4 fences although it only needs to preserve [StoreLoad] since the other fences are automatically provided.

For more information about this topic see ["A primer on memory consistency and cache coherence 2e"](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Emarkhill/papers/primer2020_2nd_edition.pdf) which is available for free.

Note 1:
A frequent requirement of the memory model is that some kind of total order over all loads and stores in that memory models exist that explain the execution. This can be done by using a topological sort.

Note 2:
Any requirement in the memory order can be violated as long as nobody is able to observe it.

Note 3:
If there is a total order of loads/stores (either per location or for all locations) a load needs to see the most recent store before it in the memory order.

Answer (score 0):

Strict consistency is distinguishable from sequential consistency when implicit writes are present. Implicit writes are not unheard-of when dealing with I/O devices.

One obvious example would be a clock; a clock has an implicit write at every clock tick independent of reads.

A perhaps more meaningful example would be a buffer presented as a single word address. Writes to the buffer would only become visible after previous writes have been read, so even if such writes were visible to the consistency mechanism as updating that address the order of the visibility of writes would depend on the order of the reads of the buffer. The writes might be effectively invisible to the consistency mechanism because they come from non-coherent I/O activity or because the interface specifies a different address for adding a value to the buffer from the address used for taking a value from the buffer (where a read from the write address might provide the number of buffer entries filled or the number vacant).

A shared pseudorandom number generator or access counter would have a similar read side effect of advancing the position in a "buffer".

The C programming language's `volatile` keyword informs the compiler that a variable can change without explicit writes, recognizing a distinction at the level of programming language between strict consistency and sequential consistency.